# How to run ionic app in live mode so that I can get the console logs?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to run my ionic app which actually runs on a device in live mode. In [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html) they guided to run

```
$ ionic run ios [options]
```

So, I tried

```
$ ionic run android -c -s
```

But once my app installed successfully, terminal got closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `ionic run android -c -l`, which activates console output and live update. All this works over wifi, so you don't need the phone to be connected by USB after you uploaded the APK.

Live update causes the app to automatically refresh when you make changes to the code, so you don't have to rebuild the APK every time. I'm not sure, but I think I read somewhere that you must have live update enabled to have console output.

Comment: so my device and the pc are connected to the same network, right?

Comment: seems convincing,, do you have any idea about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38095644/how-to-use-ionic-cordova-prefernces ?