# How to use ionic cordova preferences?

Tags: ionic-framework

Currently I'm using [cordova app preferences](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/preferences/) to store some data with today's date as key.

```
var pref = $cordovaPreferences.fetch(date, 'dates').$$state.status;
if (pref===0) {
      var out = $cordovaPreferences.store(date, '1', 'dates');
      dbPopup('store' + JSON.stringify(out));
```

}

But both the fetch and store methods always displays the status as 0. I didn't uninstall my app for every time. Since uninstallation of app removes the stored preferences..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `$window.localStorage`. It also uses keys to save strings. You can use `JSON.stringify` to convert objects to a string.

An example can be found here: http://codepen.io/drewrygh/pen/ciozB

Comment: does it be a permanent storage? Data should got deleted only when the app is uninstalled not on app exit.

Comment: Yes, it's permanent, although i don't know what happens to it when you uninstall the app

Comment: i don't care about the uninstallation, but what if I exit the app? does the value still remains once we access the local storage?

Comment: Hi @JurClerkx, I have a doubt.. May I ask you?

Comment: I have created local notif through https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples . does the notification would fire if we failed to open the app?